# Is there a "clean" way to check if the linked list node is NULL before reading its value?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have the following code to merge two sorted linked lists:

```
typedef struct ListNode ListNode;

struct ListNode* mergeTwoLists(struct ListNode* list1, struct ListNode* list2){
    ListNode    *out = NULL;

    while (list1 != NULL || list2 != NULL){
        if (list1->val <= list2->val){
            if (out != NULL){
                out->next = list1;
                out = out->next;
            }
            else {
                out = list1;
            }
            list1 = list1->next;
        }
        else {
            if (out != NULL){
                out->next = list2;
                out = out->next;
            }
            else {
                out = list2;
            }
            list2 = list2->next;
        }
    }
    return (out);
}
```

However I will get a runtime error on the first if because I'm not checking if they are null or not.

Is there any clean way to do this?

Comment: The most common way to handle this is to have the loop check if *both* pointers are non-NULL, then follow the loop with two post-loops that handle the case where only `list1` or only `list2` are non-NULL.  That tends to be simpler and faster than handling all cases in a single combined loop.

Comment: Your `list1 != NULL || list2 != NULL` test should surely be `list1 != NULL && list2 != NULL`. Both pointers need to be valid (i.e. non-null) for the very next line of code to not cause a crash.

Comment: Side note: likely you've just used imprecise language, but do be sure to distinguish between a node being null (which is nonsense) and a node *pointer* being null, which is what you're actually talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn’t get any cleaner than `if (node)`.

Since you have `typedef`ed your struct type, you can drop the `struct` keyword when you use it.

Be careful with your `out`: presumably you want to return the *head* of the new list, and not the *tail*. You’ll have to keep track of the new head (to return to the caller) and the tail (for appending) separately. Fortunately there’s a cool trick you can use.

As **Tom Karzes** mentioned in his comment, the common way to perform a merge is with three loops, two of which will be used. Since we are messing with linked lists, the final two loops reduce to a simple test-and-join each:

```
ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* list1, ListNode* list2)
{
  ListNode  head = { 0, NULL };  // faux head node
  ListNode* tail = &head;        // tail node for appending

  // While (list1 has elements) and (list2 has elements)..
  while (list1 && list2)
  {
    // ..extract head of list1 or list2 and append it to tail
    if (list2->val < list1->val) { tail->next = list2; list2 = list2->next; }
    else                         { tail->next = list1; list1 = list1->next; }
    tail = tail->next;  // update tail to true tail
    tail->next = NULL;  // (finish unlinking head of list1 or list2)
  }

  // If (list1 has any remaining elements)..
  if (list1)
    tail->next = list1;  // ..append it to tail

  // If (list2 has any remaining elements)..
  if (list2)
    tail->next = list2;  // ..append it to tail

  // Return the merged lists (without our faux head, of course)
  return head->next;
}
```

Notice how we don’t bother to try to find the tail again between the last two <s>loops</s> test-and-joins? This is because a *maximum* of only one of the conditions will be true, right?

Also, recursion is a cool trick, but in languages like C (and C++) you should generally opt away from it over large lists — especially when a simple loop will do. It is far too easy to smash the stack with code that cannot be optimized with tailcall recursion, such as **MiguelP**’s otherwise very cool example.

Answer (score 0):

TomKarzes answer is the best and yields something like:

```
struct ListNode* mergeTwoLists(struct ListNode* list1, struct ListNode* list2){
    ListNode    *head = NULL;
    ListNode    *temp = NULL;

    while (list1 != NULL || list2 != NULL){
        if (list1 && list2 && list1->val <= list2->val){
            if (head != NULL){
                temp->next = list1;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else {
                head = list1;
                temp = head;
            }
            list1 = list1->next;
        }
        else if (list1 && list2 && list1->val > list2->val){
            if (head != NULL){
                temp->next = list2;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else {
                head = list2;
                temp = head;
            }
            list2 = list2->next;
        }
        else if (!list2 && list1){
            if (head != NULL){
                temp->next = list1;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else {
                head = list1;
                temp = head;
            }
            list1 = list1->next;
        }
        else if (!list1 && list2){
            if (head != NULL){
                temp->next = list2;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else {
                head = list2;
                temp = head;
            }
            list2 = list2->next;
        }
    }
    return (head);
}
```

Which has a lot of repeated code hence a recursive approach might be cleaner:

```
struct ListNode* mergeTwoLists(struct ListNode* list1, struct ListNode* list2){
        if (!list1)
            return list2;
        else if (!list2)
            return list1;
        else if (list1->val <= list2->val){
            list1->next = mergeTwoLists(list1->next, list2);
            return list1;
        }
        else if (list1->val > list2->val){
            list2->next = mergeTwoLists(list1, list2->next);
            return list2;
        }
        return NULL;
}
```