# Merge sort using linked list with tracking the tail as well

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am implementing merge sort using linked list and I have taken some insight from some online code after I understood. When I follow the logic of the code, it makes sense to me, but I can't seem to be able to track the tail of the list inside the merge function, is it impossible with this recursive implementation? Contrary to many implementations, I want to track the tail, for the simple reason that we might need to use that sorted list for some other purposes where the tail will be important.

```
void split_half(List* orig_list, List* left, List* right) { // using Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm 
    Node* orig_head = orig_list->head;
    if (orig_head != NULL && orig_head->next != NULL) {
        Node* slow = orig_head, *fast = orig_head->next;
        while (fast != NULL) {
            fast = fast->next;
            if (fast != NULL) {
                slow = slow->next;
                fast = fast->next;
            }
        }
        left->head = orig_head;
        right->head = slow->next;
        slow->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        left->head = orig_head;
        right->head = NULL;
    }
}

Node* merge(List* list, Node* left, Node* right) {
    if (left == NULL)
        return right;   
    else if (right == NULL)
        return left;
     
    Node* merged_head = NULL, *merged_tail = NULL;;
    if (left->data <= right->data) {
        merged_head = left;
        merged_head->next = merge(list, left->next, right);
    }
    else {
        merged_head = right;
        merged_head->next = merge(list, left, right->next);
    }
    list->head = merged_head;
    list->tail = merged_tail;
    return merged_head;
}

void merge_sort(List* list) { // slow: 5
    if (list->head != NULL && list->head->next != NULL) {
        List left = list_init, right = list_init;
        split_half(list, &left, &right);
        merge_sort(&left);
        merge_sort(&right);
        Node* left_head = left.head, *right_head = right.head;
        merge(list, left_head, right_head);
    }
}

int main() {
    #define MAX 3
    int n = MAX;
    List l1 = list_init;
    int arr[MAX] = {2, 0, 5};
    if (!arr) return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        append_sll(&l1, arr[i]);
    merge_sort(&l1);
    print_sll(&l1);
    // clear_sll(&l1);

    return 0;
}
```

For my linked list, this is it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;
 
 
//---------------List------------------
typedef struct List {
    int size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail; 
} List;
 
const List list_init = { .size = 0, .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
 
Node* create_node(List *l, int elm) {
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof * node);
    if (!node) return node;
    node->data = elm;
    node->next = NULL;
    l->size++;
    return node;
}
 
Node* get_tail(List *l) {
    return l->tail;
}
 
int is_empty_sll(List *l) {
    return l->head == NULL;
}
 
int size_sll(List *l) {
    return l->size;
}
 
Node* node_k_sll(List *l, size_t k) { // 0-based index
    if (!is_empty_sll(l) && (k >= 0 && k <= size_sll(l) -1))  {
        Node* node = l->head;
        while (k--)
            node = node->next;
        return node;
    }
    printf("Invalid k or List is Empty");
    return NULL;
}
 
void append_sll(List *l, int elm) { //O(1)
    Node* cur = create_node(l, elm);
    if (!l->head) {
        l->head = cur;
    }
    else {
        l->tail->next = cur;
    }
    l->tail = cur;
}
 
void prepend_sll(List *l, int elm) {
    Node* updated_head = create_node(l, elm);
    if (!l->head) {
        l->head = updated_head;
        l->tail = l->head;
    }
    else {
        updated_head->next = l->head;
        l->head = updated_head;
    }
}
 
void insert_sll(List *l, int elm, size_t i) {
    size_t n = size_sll(l);
    if (is_empty_sll(l)) {
        printf("List Is Empty");
    }
    else if (i == 0) {
        return prepend_sll(l, elm);
    }
    else if (i == n) {
        return append_sll(l, elm);
    }
    if (i > 0 && i < n) { 
        Node* cur = create_node(l, elm);
        Node* last = l->head;
        while (--i)
            last = last->next;
        cur->next = last->next;
        last->next = cur;
    }
    else 
        printf("Invalid i");
}

void swap_sll(Node* p, Node* q) {// swap value of position i with j
    int temp = p->data;
    p->data = q->data;
    q->data = temp;
}
 
void print_sll(List *l) {
    for(Node* trav = l->head; trav != NULL; trav = trav->next)
        printf("%d ", trav->data);    
    printf("\n");
}
 
void clear_sll(List *l) { //O(n)
    while (l->head) {
        Node* temp = l->head;
        l->head = l->head->next;
        free(temp);
        l->size -= 1;
    }
    l->tail = NULL; //if not, it stays dangling
    printf("List Cleared!\n");
}

 
void delete_front_sll(List *l) {
    if (!is_empty_sll(l))
        delete_sll(l, l->head->data);
    else
        printf("List is Empty!");
}

void delete_back_sll(List *l) {
    if (!is_empty_sll(l)) {
        Node* node = l->tail;
        l->tail = prev_node(l, l->tail);
        if (l->tail) 
            l->tail->next = NULL;
         else
            l->head = NULL;
        l->size--;
        free(node);
    }
    else 
        printf("List is Empty!");
}

void delete_node(List *l, Node* node) {
    if (node == l->head)
        delete_front_sll(l);
    else if (node == l->tail)
        delete_back_sll(l);
    else {
        Node* prev = prev_node(l, node);
        prev->next = node->next;
        free(node);
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "clean" way to check if the linked list node is NULL before reading its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75324086/is-there-a-clean-way-to-check-if-the-linked-list-node-is-null-before-reading-i)

Comment: @Dúthomhas No, at least I don't know how, the concept is not clear to me

Comment: During the successive calls to helper functions, maintaining a concept of "the tail node" only makes the code complicated and error prone. Once the shuffling of nodes is complete, it is trivial to determine the last node on the list. Write simple code, not intricate code.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I totally agree with you, if I just wanted to write a simple code, I could've even evaded recursion in this situation, because an iterative one is already sufficient, though I am just looking at how to have tail without doing while loop from the head and then get the tail assigned with a temp node, I mean, I am sure there is a logic for a tail in the merge function, in an iterative solution, that would be integrated easily without looking for an additional while loop to assign the tail

Comment: I can only repeat: KISS... Strive for simplicity, not complexity...

Comment: I am not writing code for a company, I am trying to learn and that s all, and it's not wrong to challenge oneself sometimes, with complexity comes simplicity, meaning, with good understanding, simplicity comes in

Comment: Your code references `delete_sll`, but it is not defined. Also, why would you pass the *data* of the node to that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a few changes:

- Make use of the code you already have. For instance to split a list in halves, you can use `size_sll` and `node_k_sll`.
- Define a `create_list` function just as you have `create_node`.
- Make the merge iterative instead of recursive, to save on stack space.
- Give `List` pointers to `merge` instead of `Node` pointers, so that you have size and tail information.
- Have `merge` add the nodes into the left list so you don't need a third argument.
- Have `split_half` truncate the original list, so it becomes the left half, and *return* the pointer to the right half list.

Suggested update to your code:

```
List* create_list() {
    List* list = malloc(sizeof * list);
    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    return list;
}

List* split_half(List* list) { // Truncate the given list to the left-half and return the right half
    List *right = create_list();
    int n = size_sll(list);
    if (n == 0) return right;
    Node* tail = node_k_sll(list, (n - 1) / 2); // Use the functions you already have
    right->head = tail->next;
    right->tail = list->tail;
    right->size = n - (n + 1) / 2;

    list->tail = tail;
    list->size = (n + 1) / 2;
    tail->next = NULL;
    return right;
}

void merge(List* list, List* rightList) { // Merge all nodes from right list into left list
    Node *left = list->head;
    Node *right = rightList->head;
    list->size += rightList->size;
    if (right == NULL || left != NULL && left->data <= right->data) {
        if (left != NULL) left = left->next;
    } else {
        list->head = right;
        right = right->next;
    }
    Node *tail = list->head;
    // Iterative instead of recursive merge
    while (left != NULL && right != NULL) {
        if (left->data <= right->data) {
            tail->next = left;
            left = left->next;
        } else {
            tail->next = right;
            right = right->next;
        }
        tail = tail->next; 
    }
    // One list has been consumed. Append the other remaining nodes
    if (left != NULL) {
        tail->next = left;
    } else {
        tail->next = right;
        list->tail = rightList->tail;
    }    
    // Empty the right list
    rightList->head = rightList->tail = NULL;
    rightList->size = 0;
}

void merge_sort(List* list) {
    if (list->head != NULL && list->head->next != NULL) {
        List *right = split_half(list);
        merge_sort(list);
        merge_sort(right);
        merge(list, right);
    }
}

int main() {
    #define MAX 10
    int n = MAX;
    List l1 = list_init;
    int arr[MAX] = {2, 0, 5, 8, 1, 6, 7, 9, 4, 3};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        append_sll(&l1, arr[i]);
    merge_sort(&l1);
    print_sll(&l1);
    printf("size: %d\n", l1.size);
    printf("tail: %d\n", l1.tail->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 for reaching out to learn.  But tracking the tail through the entire sort is likely to require more work than just waiting until the list is sorted and traversing it one more time to get the tail. Remember the mergesort will be traversing the list about log_2 n times anyway.

If you had an unusual situation where that final pass really is a big deal - maybe the list is extremely long so traversing it requires page swaps - then the best approach is probably to implement a normal mergesort and then add a version of `merge()` that returns the tail and use that *just for the final merge pass*.

You can get a sense of the additional complexity added by using full blown queues from a coding that gets more directly to the point:

```c
LIST_NODE *sort(LIST_NODE *a) {
  if (!a || !a->next) return a;
  // Find midpoint.
  LIST_NODE *b, *t;
  for (t = a, b = a->next; b && b->next; t = t->next, b = b->next->next) ;
  // Split the input into two sub-lists of similar size.
  b = t->next;
  t->next = NULL;
  // Sort recursively.
  a = sort(a);
  b = sort(b);
  // Merge the sub-lists. d is a dummy head node for the result.
  LIST_NODE d[1] = {{NULL}};
  t = d;
  while (a && b) {
    if (a->val < b->val) {
      t->next = a;
      t = a;
      a = a->next;
    } else {
      t->next = b;
      t = b;
      b = b->next;
    }
  }
  // At least one sub-list is gone. Append the other as-is.
  t->next = a ? a : b;
  // Return the result minus the dummy head.
  return d->next;
}
```

Note this uses a standard trick for simplifying the merge operation: a dummy head node so that adding the first element to the result list does not require a null check and branch. Branches are the enemy of speed.